# PHP and csv report calculations

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a csv file that I would like to generate a summary report from. The csv looks like this :

[image]

The csv has in each row an activity and the coresponding time when it starts.

The summary I'm trying to generate has to look like this :

[image]

Basically I need to show each activity and the times when it starts and it ends

I did as following in PHP, I'm almost done but the result I get is not really what I want :

```
$csvFileName = "The csv path";
$report = array();
$file = fopen($csvFileName, "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 8000, "\n")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        $t = explode(',', $data[$c]);
        $time = $t[0];
        $activity = $t[1];
    $report[] = array($activity, $time);
    }
}
fclose($file);
//I'm reading the whole file content and copying it into an array.
$summaryReport = array();
$j = 1;
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($report); $i++){
  if($report[$i][0] !== $report[$j][0]){
   array_push($summaryReport,array($report[$i][0],$report[$i][1],$report[$j][1]));
  }
  $j++;
}
echo json_encode($summaryReport);
```

The output json looks like this :

```
[["Start","10:42","10:59"],["Driving route","11:10","11:50"],["Lunch-Rest Break","11:50","11:57"],["Driving route","11:57","12:03"],["Break","12:11","12:41"],["Driving route","13:05","14:09"],["Waiting","14:14","14:28"]]
```

What I'm looking for as result is something like that:

```
[["Start","10:42","10:59"],["Driving route","10:59","11:50"],["Lunch-Rest Break","11:50","11:57"],["Driving route","11:57","12:03"],["Break","12:03","12:41"],["Driving route","12:41","14:09"],["Waiting","14:09","14:28"],["End","14:28"]]
```

my coding logic is not really working well, does anyone see how can I do a simple loop to do what I'm looking for?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This can't work: summaryReport variable spelled without $. No semicolon after $report = array()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result can be achieved much easier. Look at my code, I got rid of all your inner loops, fixed syntax errors and there is no need to store the whole csv file in memory:

#### PHP code

```
<?php
$csvFileName = "./test.csv";
$file = fopen($csvFileName, "r");
$summaryReport = array();

$i = 0;
$previous_name = null;
while ($data = fgetcsv($file, 8000)) {
    if ($previous_name !== $data[1])
    {
        $summaryReport[$i] = array($data[1], $data[0]);
        if ($i > 0)
        {
            $summaryReport[$i-1][2] = $data[0];
        }
        $previous_name = $data[1];
        ++$i;
    }
}
fclose($file);

echo json_encode($summaryReport);
```

#### Test csv file

```
10:41,Start
10:59,Driving
11:29,Driving
11:11,End
```

#### Output

```
[["Start","10:41","10:59"],["Driving","10:59","11:11"],["End","11:11"]]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer however the json I get using your code is like that : '[["Start","10:42","10:59"],["Driving route","10:59","11:10"],["Driving route","11:10","11:50"],["Lunch-Rest Break","11:50","11:57"],["Driving route","11:57","12:03"],["Break","12:03","12:11"],["Break","12:11","12:41"],["Driving route","12:41","13:05"],["Driving route","13:05","14:09"],["Waiting","14:09","14:14"],["Waiting","14:14","14:28"],["End","14:28"]]'

Comment: What I'm looking for is a result like that: '[["Start","10:42","10:59"],["Driving route","10:59","11:50"],["Lunch-Rest Break","11:50","11:57"],["Driving route","11:57","12:03"],["Break","12:03","12:41"],["Driving route","12:41","14:09"],["Waiting","14:09","14:28"],["End","14:28"]]'

Comment: Your code is just reading the csv line by line and printing the time , what I want is to get the time when an activity starts and ends for instance I have activity "Driving route" that starts at "10:59" but ends at "11:50" so the summary for this activity should be ["Driving route","10:59","11:50"]

Comment: @OussamaLord Hi, just read your message. Will try to fix the code soon.